# Is deep copy in the Function "Model.Compile(optimizer = opt, ...)"?

Tags: python, keras

```
opt = optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=opt,...)
model.train(...)    #Step-1

opt = optimizers.Adam(lr = 0.1)
model.train(...)    #Step-2
```

So, I want to know what is learningrate in the "Step-2" ?
0.001 or 0.1?
Actually, it is not compiled after opt changing.

Comment: Step 2 still has `lr=0.001`. You need to compile the model again to change the learning rate for step 2.

Comment: You can also use a [learning rate scheduler](https://keras.io/callbacks/#learningratescheduler) callback if that's useful.